# Most secure free/libre XMPP client for Android

Tags: android, open-source, xmpp

What's the most secure XMPP client for Android right now?

Open source would be strongly preferred. My 
list for security includes:

- easy OTR support
- sensible configuration out-of-the-box, so a novice user will be reasonably secure
- out, about, tested and prodded for a while and low chance of unfixed bugs that are security relevant

... But there are folks who are far more knowledgeable about security and maybe have a better bucket list.

Answer (score 3):

### [Conversations](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=conversations&fdid=eu.siacs.conversations)

It supports OTR and OpenPGP for encryption. OTR is very quick to get going.

Comment: I would also say that there is no such thing as a secure non-open-source anything-client.

Comment: Does that mean Conversations is closed source? I'm unfamiliar with it

Comment: @Xen2050, no, Conversations is open source and believed to be secure.

Answer (score 1):

- [**Jitsi**](https://jitsi.org) advertises *"secured video calls, conferencing, chat, desktop sharing, file transfer, support for your favorite OS and IM network."*

  It supports protocols including SIP, 
  GoogleTalk, 
  XMPP (Jabber), 
  Facebook (via XMPP), 
  .NET Messenger Service (commonly known as MSN or Windows Live Messenger), 
  Yahoo! Messenger, 
  AIM, 
  ICQ.

  And has these Security features:

  - Encrypted password storage
  - Password protection with a master password
  - Encrypted Instant Messaging with Off-the-Record Messaging (OTRv4)
  - Chat authentication with the Socialist Millionaire Protocol over OTR
  - Call encryption with SRTP and ZRTP for XMPP and SIP
  - Call encryption with SRTP and SDES for XMPP and SIP
  - DNSSEC support
  - TLS support and certificate-based client authentication for SIP and XMPP

  It's available for Windows, Mac, Linux & Android.
  There's also a [Jitsi Meet](https://jitsi.org/Projects/JitsiMeet) video conferencing version for Android & iPhone, the Android version is currently on Google's Play store under [Jitsi Meet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jitsi.meet). Or the Jitsi Nightly builds (Experimental, for fearless alpha warriors only!) for Android are [here](https://download.jitsi.org/jitsi/nightly/android/) (from the main webpage's Downloads link)

- [**ChatSecure**](https://chatsecure.org/) is open source & handles OTR well. It *was* available for Android and iPhone, but now the Android version is no longer supported:

  > The developers of the Android version [...] are no longer maintaining
  >   the upstream version. If you still use ChatSecure Android you should
  >   migrate to another app immediately. For a similar user experience and
  >   the best compatibility with the latest features of ChatSecure iOS, we
  >   recommend downloading [Conversations](https://conversations.im/).

  It's been forked to [Zom-Android](https://github.com/zom/Zom-Android), see the [ChatSecure FAQ](https://chatsecure.org/faq/) for more info. ChatSecure is:

  > ChatSecure is a free and open source messaging app that features OTR encryption over XMPP. You can connect to your
  >   existing accounts on Facebook or Google, create new accounts on public XMPP servers (including via Tor ), or even
  >   connect to your own server for extra security.
  >
  > Unlike other apps that keep you stuck in their walled garden, ChatSecure is fully interoperable with other clients that
  >   support OTR and XMPP, such as Adium , Jitsi , and more.

---

Also see [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org) for "*an installable catalogue of FOSS (Free and Open Source Software) applications for the Android platform. The client makes it easy to browse, install, and keep track of updates on your device.*" It's really good, and very similar to other Linux software repositories, but for FOSS Android programs.